# json_encode rendering entire html page

Tags: json, ajax

this is part of drag and drop page codes.

on top of page before !doctype i have php codes sent from ajax.
My codes working order is ok but json_encode does not display succes message.

i am looking from console, i see json_encode responseText was all of the html page.

```
if(isset($_POST['eleman'])){

    $islemSonuc = array();

    if (is_array($_POST['eleman'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['eleman'] as $key => $value)
            if ($vt->query("UPDATE kategoriler SET katSira = '$key' WHERE id = '$value'"))

                $islemSonuc['tamam'] = "ok";

    }else{
                $islemSonuc['hata'] = "hata";
    }

    echo json_encode($islemSonuc);
    }



            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                method: "post",
                data: data,

                url: "dragdropLI.php",
                success: function(sonuc) {

                    if (sonuc.tamam) {

                        $("#sonuc").addClass("text-success").html(sonuc.tamam).fadeIn(500);

                        setTimeout(function() {

                            $("#sonuc").addClass("text-success").html(sonuc.tamam).fadeOut(500);

                        }, 500);


                    } else {

                        $("#sonuc").addClass("text-danger").html(sonuc.hata);

                    }

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Now i am seperated php post page, then i can see the json responseText.
Why responseText not correctly display on same page post?